# ImportError when building ROS2 Bouncy Bolson on Ubuntu 16.04 from source

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When building ROS2 BB from source I get the following ImportError:

```
--- stderr: uncrustify_vendor                                         
ImportError: 'from ament_package import parse_package_string' failed: cannot import name 'parse_package_string'
Make sure that you have installed 'ament_package', it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
```

Is there missing something in the [wiki.ros2.org install from source instructions](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Linux-Development-Setup#building-ros-2-on-linux)? Or is this related to another problem specific to my OS setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296622/importerror-when-building-ros2-bouncy-bolson-on-ubuntu-16.04-from-source/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you are using an outdated version of the code.
There are no package in Bouncy that still uses `ament_package` to parse packa`ge.xml` files. Now the package parsing is done using `catkin_pkg`. As a consequence the `parse_package_string` function [has been removed](https://github.com/ament/ament_package/pull/75) from `ament_package`

Can you make sure to download the Bouncy version of the code for all repositories?

I recommend doing it in an empty workspace to make sure you don't have any legacy Ardent repositories in your workspace.

You can do so by running:

```
mkdir -p bouncy_ws/src
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/release-latest/ros2.repos
vcs import src < ros2.repos
```

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-07-09**:
Thx for letting me know. I have setup ROS2 Bouncy on Ubuntu 18.04 via deb packages yesterday which seems to be the best fit for playing around with both, ROS2 Bouncy and ROS1 Melodic. I will not try out the "install from source" variant again but I guess the solution would have fix the issue.